# Unable to remove a "Sizelimit" property using kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I have `sizeLimit` property under `emptyDir` set to 2Gi in my template base file. I want to remove the `sizelimit` and just have `emptyDir: {}`. I've been unable to achieve this using Kustomization overlays. I will detail my folder structure and kustomization yamls below.

**Folder Structure:**

```
application
├── majorbase
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   └── resources
│       └── web-template.yaml
├── minorbase
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   └── resources
└── myoverlays
    ├── kustomization.yaml
    └── resources
        └── my-new-web.yaml
```

The folder `myoverlays` contains the following contents in it's kustomization.yaml file

```
bases:
- ../minorbase
patchesStrategicMerge:
- resources/my-new-web.yaml
```

The folder `minorbase` contains the following contents in it's kustomization.yaml file

```
bases:
- ../majorbase
```

The folder `majorbase` contains the following contents in it's kustomization.yaml file

```
resources:
- resources/web-template.yaml
```

The section I want to edit looks like this in the majorbase/template.

```
volumes:
      - name: test-vol
        emptyDir:
          sizeLimit: "2Gi"
```

The above configuration needs to be updated using overlays as below.

```
volumes:
      - name: test-vol
        emptyDir: {}
```

This is where my problem lies. Kustomization just picks the 2Gi value mentioned in the base whenever I remove the `sizelimit` in my overlays. When I mention different value to `sizeLimit` such as "1Gi" in my overlays file, kustomization is picking up the change. What is the cause of this behaviour? Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NB: This answer assumes a recent version of Kustomize (I'm running 4.5.2 locally). Your examples are using deprecated syntax (the `bases` section was deprecated [in version 2.1.0](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/661743c7e5bd8c3d9d6866b6bc0a6f0e0b0512eb/site/content/en/blog/releases/v2.1.0.md#resources-expanded-bases-deprecated), for example).

---

Your problem is that you're using a `strategicMerge` patch, and you're merging and empty map (`{}`) with `{"sizeLimit": "26gi"}`. If you merge an empty map with anything, it's a no-op: you end up with the "anything".

To explicitly delete an element, you have a few choices.

You can use the `$patch: replace` directive (you can find an example of that [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/inlinePatch.md)) to have Kustomize *replace* the `emptyDir` element, rather than merging the contents. That would look like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: test-vol
      emptyDir:
        $patch: replace
```

The corresponding `kustomization.yaml` might look something like:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - ../../base

patches:
  - path: resources/my-new-web.yaml
```

---

Alternately, you can use a JSONPatch patch, which is good for explicitly deleting fields:

```
- path: /spec/volumes/0/emptyDir/sizeLimit
  op: remove
```

Where `kustomization.yaml` would look like:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - ....//base

patches:
  - target:
      kind: Pod
      name: example
    path: resources/my-new-web.yaml
```

---

You can find a complete runnable demonstration of this [here](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-72086055).